# Does Apache spawn piped logger on each HTTP request?

Tags: apache-2.2, pipe, cronolog, prefork

I am examining a high-volume Apache *prefork* site and noticing that many log entries such as:

```
CustomLog '|/foo/bar/cronolog -foo -bar'
RewriteLog '|/foo/bar/cronolog -bar -foo'
```

When apache logs the request or the rewrite is cronolog **spawned for EACH request or is the pipe opened and written-to for the lifetime duration of the preforked apache process?**

(This was asked on stackoverflow but I'll remove from there as more applicable here I think.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is spawned once per CustomLog directive.

So on my server where I use these two directives in the global scope only one copy of cronolog started and used for writing logs.

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedvhost
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/apache2/%Y%m.combined.allhosts.log" combinedvhost
```

Comment: OK, thank you.  What this means I hope is that all forked processes would dup() the pipe? Curious how it synchronizes record output.  Where I'm going with that:  is there a performance hit with a lot of CustomLog's?